# How to make the math font slightly thicker?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, pdftex, typography, latin-modern

I'd like to use TeX Gyre Schola as my text font and the default LaTeX font for the math mode. (*Side question: is the default font Latin Modern in math mode or another font?*)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
This is some text.
\[ F_\mathrm{D} = m \ddot z = b \lambda \rho \frac{I}{P_0} \vec{c} \]
Sadly, the math is less thick than the text.
\end{document}
```

While both look great on their own, IMHO, the drawback is that the math font is much more "thin" or less "thick" than the text font.

**Is there a way to keep this math font and make it slightly thicker, but not bold, with pdfLaTeX?**

Comment: Nice question! I'd like to know if there is a way to locally make certain math characters slightly *thinner*. For example, the letter $\Psi$ looks almost bold by default and so stands out on a page; it's kinda ugly.

Comment: If you don't load `unicode-math` or any math font package, then Computer Modern will be used, which doesn't really match with New Century Schoolbook. You could try `\usepackage{fouriernc}`

Comment: @egreg `fourier` + `tgschola` looks a lot different from `fouriernc` (both in text and in math). I like `tgschola` much more. But the "officially" matching `fourier` has some rather big spaces on some sub- and superscript combinations that look rather strange without lots of manually tweaking. That's why I wanted to try something different.

Answer (score 10):

(Note: After my answer, the OP specified that a pdfLaTeX solution is wanted.) Xe(La)TeX offers the `FakeBold` font feature -- meant for *"rare situations [when] users may want to mechanically distort the shapes of the glyphs in the current font"* (`fontspec` manual, section 10.13). Use at your own risk. ;-)

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont[FakeBold=0.5]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
This is some text.
\[ F_\mathrm{D} = m \ddot z = b \lambda \rho \frac{I}{P_0} \vec{c} \]
Sadly, the math is less thick than the text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Output without `FakeBold`:

[image]

Comment: So, there's no `pdfLaTeX` way?

Comment: @FooBar I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
\usepackage{fouriernc}
```

or

```
\usepackage{millennial}
```

or

```
\usepackage{fourier}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{tgschola}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your cited packages are doing and why they can be a solution? Your answer is unclear til now ...

Comment: I don't know about `millennial`; I know `fourier`, but it uses Utopia, rather than New Century Schoolbook (they aren't the same font). On the other hand, `fouriernc` provides a math font for New Century Schoolbook that *can* be used along with `tgschola`: all is needed is to load `fouriernc` before `tgschola`.