Layout and fonts of Berger and Gostiaux book in contemporary (La)TeX
I would like to reproduce the old-style TeX layout of some Springer books from the 80s and 90s, like this one: 
As far as I understand, TeX fonts have been replaced in later years (see for instance $\delta$). Is there any chance to have some reasonably good layout which reproduces the appearance of those documents in contemporary TeX systems?
Thank you in advance.

the image is a bit fuzzy but what differences are you seeing in \delta?

oh it is tex, by Silvio Levy:

see this almost duplicate question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/640652/1090  I would guess this is amstex using am fonts but mlmodern has been suggested there as a more modern replacement closer in weight than the current type1 cm fonts

@DavidCarlisle I see, it seems that the fonts I like are hated by the whole community, so they just disappeared many many years ago. I know mlmodern fonts, but (of course) math fonts have been replaced. The old am fonts were abandoned, as I read in a FAQ.

sure no one uses am anymore but they could be found in the archives, but  they are bitmap fonts so don't really work well in modern workflows or pdf etc but still they should still be usable if you really want them.
