New Computer Modern without unicode-math?
I like the thickness of the book weight version of New Computer Modern. However, New Computer Modern seems to require unicode-math, which changes some of the mathematics typesetting in ways I don't like. For example, a_1, \dots, a_m looks as follows:
 (Latin Modern)
Generated using:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\[a_1, \dots, a_m\]

\end{document}

 (New Computer Modern, book weight)
Generated using:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}

\[a_1, \dots, a_m\]

\end{document}

Instead of the fontsetup line, I also tried using:
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

And also:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    Extension      = .otf,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    BoldFont       = NewCM10-Bold,
    ItalicFont     = NewCM10-BookItalic,
]{NewCM10-Book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}

but the output was (at least to me) indistinguishable from the fontspec version.
In the New Computer Modern version, the dots look cramped, and also the the subscripts look too low (especially the m, which is almost entirely under the a). I believe this happens because in order to load the math font, New Computer Modern is bringing in unicode-math.
Is there any way to use the thickness of the New Computer Modern font, but to keep all of the math typesetting as it is in Latin Modern, such as by not loading unicode-math or by telling unicode-math to go back to "classical" math typesetting?
(I am using TeX Live 2024 with LuaLaTeX, in case that matters.)

Can you please provide code for both examples. The three dots in your latin modern example does not look as the ones from the open type font, for example. Also, the vertical placement of the subscripts can be controlled with font parameters.

welcome! can you please provide code we can compile to produce each example you show? is the LM example using the opentype font or a 7-bit setup?

@mickep it is certainly close to the 7-bit output. and certainly the lm dots look completely different in opentype - similar to the new cm shown here, but not as heavy.

If you are using NewComputerModern book variant then it is recommended to load NewCMMath-Book font for math characters. This math font is Unicode. If you want to keep the old 7bit math with book text variant then the math characters will be not "book" because such a variant doesn't exist in classical Computer Modern 7bit. The unicode math font has different metric for subscripts positions as you note. This can be overwritten (depending on LuaTeX or XeTeX is used). The \dots is a simple macro which can be defined as in original plain TeX without problems.

@mickep and cfr I have added the code to generate the images. Apologies for the oversight; I thought my example was simple enough that I didn't need to provide code, but clearly I was wrong.

Good update! (+1). Have you tried mlmodern? I did not test, but maybe \usepackage{mlmodern} will give you the boldness you look for.

While mlmodern is an option , it is much much thicker than newcm book. Mlmodern will look very thick for people on macs. Also, newcm has many many symbols, by orders of magnitude greater than mlmodern. For example, mlmodern doesn't have blackboard bold, newcm has.

Btw, are these two (dots and subscript positions) the only problems that you're facing, or are there other problems too?

@mickep Yes, I have tried MLModern. Unfortunately as Apoorv Potnis says, MLModern looks overpoweringly thick on some PDF viewers (such as the built-in PDF viewer on Firefox on Windows). My interest in New Computer Modern is because it makes Computer Modern slightly thicker, such that it appears good on all the PDF viewers I have tried.

@ApoorvPotnis The only other thing I have noticed is that the upper limit in \sum expressions is positioned a little differently, though this one seems okay to me, but there's probably more differences that I haven't noticed yet. It's looking like there's no way to just turn off unicode-math, so I may have follow-up questions here as I notice more differences.

I don't it's possible to use the full NewCM fonts without unicode-math. In order to use a font in pdflatex, you probably need to create support files like tfm and map. But there's hope. NewCM has been designed to be metrically compatible with LM (with unicode math). So, if one replaces the references to LM fonts in the lmodern package files to newcm, it should probably work, I guess. However, I don't really now how to do it.

There's one more thing that seems possible in principle. Create the document with lmodern fonts, and then somehow change all the references to lm fonts in the resulting pdf to the newcm fonts. I say it should work in principle, because both the fonts are metrically the same. But I am not aware of any method to replace fonts of a pdf. Perhaps commercial pdf editors such as adobe acrobat and foxit have this ability.

But I think it's just better and easier to use unicode math, and edit the specific typesetting preferences manually as in David's answer.

You may find this answer by mickep to be useful, if you are fine with bitmap fonts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261038/128462

What we can do in OpTeX:
\loadmath{NewCMMath-Book}
\fontfam[newcm]
\book\rm
\Umathsubshiftdown\textstyle=1.5pt
\Umathsubshiftdown\displaystyle=1.7pt

Test: $a_1\dots a_m$.

$$
   a_1\dots a_m
$$

\bye

The NewCMMath-Book font for Unicode math is loaded and \book variant for text fonts is used.
You can see that \dots macro isn't redefined in OpTeX and we need not to do nothing with it. On the other hand the subscript positions is corrected by \Umathsubshiftdown LuaTeX primitive (OpTeX runs only with LuaTeX so we need not to create an alternative solution for XeTeX).

It's not really a font choice so much as unicode-math. one is using the ellipsis character from the font, the other is using three spaced dots. You can restore the original version easily enough.

\documentclass{article}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy\Xmathellipsis\mathellipsis
  \RenewDocumentCommand\mathellipsis{}{\mathinner {\ldotp \ldotp \ldotp }}%
  }
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}



\[a_1, \dots, a_m, \mathellipsis, a_2, \Xmathellipsis, a_3 \]

\end{document}


I can see that this works for \ldots, but not for \cdots or \ddots. Is there a way to restore all such differences at once, or do I need to discover each change and manually fix it?

@IssaRice you are undoing a specific choice of the unicode package to use the … character, there is no general issue here.
